# Typescript class method, constrained to class properties

Tags: typescript

Given the following class:

```
class MyOb {
  foo: string; 

  setFields(props) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }
}
```

Is it possible to constrain the `props` parameter of `setFields` to the properties of `MyObj`?   So that:

```
new MyOb().setFields({ foo: 'bar' })  // compiles
new MyOb().setFields({ x: 'bar' })    // fails, property x is not a part of MyOb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `keyof` and mapped types:

```
setFields(props: { [TKey in keyof MyOb]?: MyOb[TKey] } ) {
```

Note the `?`, since you want each property to be optional.

[Demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20MyOb%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20setFields(props%3A%20%7B%20%5BTKey%20in%20keyof%20MyOb%5D%3F%3A%20MyOb%5BTKey%5D%20%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20props)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Anew%20MyOb().setFields(%7B%20foo%3A%20'bar'%20%7D)%20%20%2F%2F%20compiles%0Anew%20MyOb().setFields(%7B%20x%3A%20'bar'%20%7D)%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20fails%2C%20property%20x%20is%20not%20a%20part%20of%20MyOb)

[Docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: I'd note that this will only allow you to set the public properties and methods of the class, but not private or protected ones. That's fine (even preferable) in most cases but it's something to be aware of.